# Haskell and lazy Monads evaluation

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

While playing with monads I often incur in problems of evaluation. Now, I understand the basic concepts of lazy evaluation, but I don't get how monads are lazily evaluated in Haskell.

Consider the following code

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import System

main = print <$> head <$> getArgs
```

In my mind it should the main function should print the first console argument, but it doesn't.

I know that

```
getArgs :: IO [String]
head <$> getArgs :: IO String
print <$> (head <$> getArgs) :: IO (IO ())
main :: IO (IO ())
```

so apparently, the first argument is not printed on the stdout because the content of the first monad IO is not evaluated. So if I join the two monads, it works.

```
main = join $ print <$> head <$> getArgs
```

Would anyone, please, clarify it for me? (or give me a pointer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haskell 2010 Report (the language definition) [says](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005):

> The value of the program is the value of the identifier `main` in module
>   `Main`, which must be a computation of type `IO τ` for some type `τ`.
>   When the program is executed, the computation `main` is
>   performed, and its result (of type `τ`) is discarded.

Your `main` function has type `IO (IO ())`. The quote above means that only the outer action (`IO (IO ())`) is evaluated, and its result (`IO ()`) is discarded. How did you get here? Let's look at the type of `print <$>`:

```
> :t (print <$>)
(print <$>) :: (Show a, Functor f) => f a -> f (IO ())
```

So the problem is that you used `fmap` in conjunction with `print`. Looking at the definition of `Functor` instance for `IO`:

```
instance  Functor IO where
   fmap f x = x >>= (return . f)
```

you can see that that made your expression equivalent to `(head <$> getArgs >>= return . print)`. To do what you originally intended, just remove the unnecessary `return`:

```
head <$> getArgs >>= print
```

Or, equivalently:

```
print =<< head <$> getArgs
```

Note that IO actions in Haskell are just like other values - they can be passed to and returned from functions, stored in lists and other data structures, etc. An IO action is not evaluated unless it's a part of the main computation. To "glue" IO actions together, use `>>` and `>>=`, not `fmap` (which is typically used for mapping *pure* functions over values in some "box" - in your case, `IO`).

Note also that this has to do not with lazy evaluation, but purity - semantically, your program is a pure function that returns a value of type `IO a`, which is then interpreted by the runtime system. Since your inner `IO` action is not part of this computation, the runtime system just discards it. A nice introduction to these issues is the second chapter of Simon Peyton Jones's ["Tackling the Awkward Squad"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exhaustive response.

Comment: So basically what I did was to execute getArgs (the outer IO) and throw the results into something that was never executed (because ignored by main).

Comment: Correct. You code executes `head <$> getArgs` and then feeds its result to `return . print`, which has the type `a -> IO (IO ())`.

Comment: Although, `head` is not evaluated because its result is not needed, so your code will never produce an "empty list" exception. You can test this by changing `getArgs` to `getLine`.

Answer (score 4):

You have `head <$> getArgs :: IO String` and `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`, i.e. a value in a monad and a function from a plain value to a monad. The function used to compose such things is the monadic bind operator `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

So what you want is

```
main = head <$> getArgs >>= print
```

`(<$>)` aka `fmap` has the type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so it is useful when you want to apply a *pure* function to some value in a monad, which is why it works with `head` but not with `print`, since `print` is not pure.